# Check if label exists in Kubernetes config for elk using puppet

Tags: kubernetes, puppet, elastic-stack

I am new to Stackoverflow, puppet and kubernetes as well.

I need to create an if conditional, to check if a certain label exist in the environment field for kubernetes label in Kibana Filters, using puppet and if it does not exist it will add it.
 This is what I have so far, and where reads ??  -is where I am not sure what goes there, I have tought about setting a regex,

```
if [kubernetes] {   
  if [kubernetes][labels][app_kubernetes_io\/environment] = ?? {
    mutate { add_field => { "environment" => [kubernetes][labels][app_kubernetes_io\/environment]  } }  
}
```

Comment: Add a label to what, a deployment? a pod? a service? try to be more specific :)

Comment: found a solution.

Comment: @anakin.thegardner please post your solution as an answer- others who will encounter similar issue might benefit from your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

} if [kubernetes][labels][app_kubernetes_io/environment] {
  mutate { add_field => { "environment" => "%{[kubernetes][labels][app_kubernetes_io/environment]}" } }
}